# Firefox download stops while screen locks

Tags: windows-7, firefox, download

I'm using Window 7. When I download a large file through Firefox browser and screen gets locked, the download stops. I want to continue downloading even if screen is locked.

How to do this.

Comment: As Ganesh says, this is possibly due to machine going to sleep mode  as opposed to locking; This *may* be helpful: http://superuser.com/questions/470721/how-do-i-set-it-so-that-my-computer-wont-go-into-auto-standby-sleep-mode-while

Answer (score 0):

It seems more like your PC goes to sleep and hence your screen gets locked. Since the PC went to sleep, Firefox paused your downloads.

Is it a laptop or PC? Can you check the Power Options (in Control Panel) to see when is the PC configured to go to sleep?

Also to verify that Firefix indeed pauses download when you lock the screen, please start a download and lock your PC. Do not wait for it to auto lock. Then unlock your PC and verify if your download paused.

Comment: Mine is a Laptop and the power option is set to go to sleep in 15 minutes. Now I've put the sleep Never. I'll see it helps.